# Recursive function to create a linked list with certain elements of another linked list in c

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

i have this recursive function:

```
struct singly* SetMinusRec(struct singly* shead1, struct singly* shead2){
    struct singly* s2end;

    s2end = shead2;

    if(shead1 == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        while(s2end != NULL && shead1->id < s2end->id){
            s2end = s2end->next;
        }
        
        struct singly* new = (struct singly*)malloc(sizeof(struct singly));

        if(shead1->id == s2end->id){
            /* How can i not add this to the list, but just move on to the next node? */
        }

        printf("-%d %d-\n", shead1->id, s2end->id);

        new->id = shead1->id;
        new->next = SetMinusRec(shead1->next, shead2);    
        return new;
    }
}
```

Basically, shead2 is sorted with decreasing order, and shead1 with increasing, and i want to create a new list, which has the elements of shead1 that dont exist in shead2. What am i supposed to do when they have the same id? How can i move on to the next node?

**Thanks a lot.**

Comment: What are you trying to do, specifically?

Comment: The [simpler but slower] O(n^2) solution is to loop through the `shead1` elements. Scan `shead2` looking for a match. If not found, add the [duplicated] `shead1` element to the new list. No recursion needed.

Comment: I have made it without recursion with O(n1 + n2) (n1=#of elements in shead1...). I am trying to do it with recursion.

Comment: The more complex [but maybe faster] solution is to recursively reverse the `shead2` list to create the `new` list. Then, scan all `new` list elements and delete the element if it's in `shead1`. In this case, you only need to look at the current element of `shead1`. You proceed to the next if shead->value < new->value. This is similar to what you do for a merge sort.

Comment: Say shead1 = {10,11,12,13} and shead2 = {9, 11, 12,14} . Then the result should be {10,13}. Thanks a lot for your replies

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post your O(n1 + n2) solution so we have an exact idea of what you want. I'm skeptical that you can do it in O(n1 + n2) without [recursively] reversing `shead2` I'd be glad to be proven wrong ;-)

Comment: `shead2 = {9, 11, 12,14}` does not conform to `shead2 is sorted with decreasing order`... Something is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This memory allocation

```
struct singly* new = (struct singly*)malloc(sizeof(struct singly));
```

can produce a memory leak if `shead1->id == s2end->id`.

On the other hand, if memory will not be allocated due to the equation and the pointer `new` will be set to `NULL` then this statement

```
new->next = SetMinusRec(shead1->next, shead2);
```

will invoke undefined behavior.

Also this if statement

```
if(shead1->id == s2end->id){
```

and this test output

```
printf("-%d %d-\n", shead1->id, s2end->id);
```

again can invoke undefined behavior if after the while loop the pointer `s2end` is equal to `NULL`.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
struct singly * SetMinusRec( const struct singly *shead1, const struct singly *shead2 )
{
    struct singly *shead = NULL;

    if ( shead1 != NULL )
    {
        const struct singly *current = shead2;

        while ( current != NULL && shead1->id < current->id )
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        if ( current == NULL || current->id < shead1->id )
        {
            shead = malloc( sizeof( struct singly ) );

            shead->id   = shead1->id;
            shead->next = SetMinusRec( shead1->next, shead2 );
        }
        else
        {
            shead = SetMinusRec( shead1->next, shead2 );
        }
    }

    return shead;
}
```